# SKBitmap.Decode(imageStream) is returning null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to use skiasharp to edit an image I have as a stream, but when I try to turn it into an `SKBitmap` the resulting variable is always none. I am using `Xam.Plugin.Media` to get the image.

```
var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { SaveToAlbum = false });

if (photo != null)
{
    var imageStream = photo.GetStream();
    SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(imageStream);
    using (SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint { TextSize = 48 })
    using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap))
    {
        canvas.DrawText("test", 0, 0, textPaint);
    }

    SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
    SKData encoded = image.Encode();
    Stream stream = encoded.AsStream();

    PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
}
```

Comment: have you verified that imageStream is valid image data?

Comment: Hi, first need to check `var imageStream = photo.GetStream();` whether be null .

Answer (score 2):

I add this line after obtaining a stream with 
`var imageStream = photo.GetStream();`

```
imageStream.seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself and was able to work around it by loading the stream into a byte array first.

```
var fs = new FileStream("Path", FileMode.Open);
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
fs.CopyTo(imageStream);

var imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
var bitmap = SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(imageBytes);
```